# Javascript function not getting whole value

Tags: javascript

I am calling `showedit` function with argument. But when i `alert` it in the function it is showing partial value.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showedit(856478546521458789);">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;float: right;"></i>
</a>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
function showedit(id) {
    alert(id);
    document.getElementById("update_status_" + id).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("status_" + id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Maybe you should write it as a string instead of a number.

Comment: Did you try to pass the number as a string? It does not look like the number is used in any math

Answer (score 1):

Send the argument as a string. See the code snippet below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showedit('856478546521458789');">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;float: right;"></i>
</a>
```

It is happening because it is exceeding JavaScript's `MAX_INT` value.